# Is it correct to mark an Object-c question as a possible duplicate for a Swift question

Tags: discussion

Lately I started to see users, with high reputations, mark questions asked for Swift as a possible duplication for questions asked in Objective-C

I understand that the problem sometimes is the same, but most of the questions ask about some mistakes in the codes. So our answers, I guess, should give a code in Swift, while making a question as a possible duplications is giving an answer in another language.

For example:
I totally agree that [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33131634/swift-nil-when-setting-the-value-of-text-field), that was asked in swift, is a possible duplication for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8033924/iboutlet-properties-does-not-update-when-using-prepareforsegue-method), that was asked in Objective-c, that is because both of them is about the life cycle of view controllers regarding the code. Plus, this case is not exclusive between Swift and Objective-c. A lot of the times we face questions about algorithms or psuedo code rather than a specific programming language. However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786566/sending-custom-http-headers-in-swift/32786812#32786812), definitely should not be a possible duplicated for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751768/nsurlsessionconfiguration-httpadditionalheaders-not-set) since it is asking about Swift code.

What do you think? Is the case of Objective-c, Swift special so we can mark questions as possible duplicated?

I highly don't think so but I need to check since I started to face a lot of these scenarios

Answer (score 3):

> *"However, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32786566/), definitely should not be a possible duplicated for [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24751768/) since it is asking about Swift code."*

The question in that first link asks for a [swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/swift) solution, which the answer in that second link provides.

***Look beyond the tags of a question when closing as dupe.***
If the question is similar enough, and the answer works, close-vote it.  Regardless of tags.<sup>*</sup>
Consider correcting the tags if they are wrong, though.

<sub>*: More or less. The dupe should be relevant, of course.</sub>

Comment: That is a mistake by the user who asked the question to accept something from different language, but as i said, if you know objective-c, you can (should) be able somehow to change your code to swift. Nevertheless, i can show you more questions on the same issue. my point here is the idea not the supporting details

Comment: _"That is a mistake by the user who asked the question to accept something from different language"_ Was it? Users usually accept answers that __work__ for them. Maybe they forgot to tag Swift, or didn't necessarily _need_ to use it.

Comment: Focus on the content of the question, not the tags. Seems legit to me.

Comment: @Gimby: Though consider correcting the tags if they are wrong...

Comment: @Deduplicator absolutely. Maybe if Cerbrus adds that to his answer people would stop downvoting it :/

Comment: Fixed. Now let's hope the dv's magically disappear.